# Jenkins behind nginx (docker)

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins

I have a nginx-container with the following location and upstream configuration:

```
upstream jenkins-docker {
  server jenkins:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf-files/jenkins-location.conf:
location /jenkins/ {
sendfile off;
  proxy_pass         http://jenkins-docker;
  proxy_redirect     off;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;

  proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

  #this is the maximum upload size
  client_max_body_size       10m;
  client_body_buffer_size    128k;

  proxy_connect_timeout      90;
  proxy_send_timeout         90;
  proxy_read_timeout         90;
  proxy_request_buffering    off; # Required for HTTP CLI commands in Jenkins > 2.54
}
```

Jenkins is in a docker container aswell. They are both connected to a docker bridge network. Inside nginx-container I can do:

curl jenkins:8080:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>
```

nginx can communicate with jenkins.

In jenkins->manage Jenkins -> Configure System under "Jenkins Location"   I changed the "Jenkins URL" to http://myIP/jenkins

When I type into my Browser myIp/jenkins it get redirect to http://myIp/login?from=%2Fjenkins%2F which results in a 404

When I change the location in nginx "location /jenkins/ {" just to "/" it works like a charm. Thats why I tried it with a rewrite:

```
rewrite ^/jenkins(.*) /$1 break;
```

When I do this I can access the jenkins dashboar with myIp/jenkis. But when I click on a menu item I get a 404

Comment: Did you mean you change the location configuration ?

Comment: Try reload from disk from jenkins if you changed any config

Comment: I restarted Jenkins. And yes I change the location configuration in nginx. I edit my question

Comment: Can you paste what exactly you changed in jenkins configuration.

Comment: In  jenkins->manage Jenkins -> Configure System under "Jenkins Location"   I changed the "Jenkins URL" to http://myIP/jenkins thats all I changed

Comment: I think you missed to specify port.  You should specify port also along with url in location. http://Your URL:8080

Comment: I changed it to myIp:8080/jenkins restarted jenkins and it still doesn't work

Comment: Why are you giving /jenkins as endpoint. Jenkins will be listening on host in http port 8080 by default. That could be the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166913/discussion-between-reasyeasypeasy-and-slashpai).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to set the `--prefix` command on your jenkins installation. You can do this in the `jenkins.xml` config file or by altering your command line arguments to include `--prefix=/jenkins`.

The arguments can be seen at https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins

Comment: How I'm doing this in a docker container? I can't find the jenkins.xml file

Comment: I added --env JENKINS_ARGS="--prefix=/jenkins" to the run command from docker. But still not working

Answer (score 3):

set an  enviroment variable like this:
 `JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"`.

If you are using docker-compose, something like this:

```
environment:
  - JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"
```